# write, update and save a well-formed xml file in as3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, filestream

I am trying to update an xml file and **save** elements **inside** of an already saved root element.

I have only found examples where the xml files are just opened and not saved. Can someone help me to find the best way to save the results?

My project right now looks like this:

I am loading an xml file via URLLoader/URLRequest and display the contents in several text fields. New text from an input field is saved (appended) via FileStream directly to the xml file in the applicationStorageDirectory (that will be on iPhone).

The new input should then be added to an on-screen list (created with a for-loop) and displayed, however, it can't get it that far. After reading the newly saved input from the xml file, I naturally get error 1088 because the xml file is not well-formed anymore.

This is because the input is appended after the root element and the result looks like this:

```
<root>
  <message></message>
  <date></date>
</root>
  <message>new input</message>
  <date></date>
```

When of course what I want is this:

```
<root>
  <message></message>
  <date></date>
  <message>new input</message>
  <date></date>
</root>
```

But I have no idea how i can achieve that.

I made several attempts to avoid having to append, like loading the xml content, changing it, and then writing everything again. But since I am still new to as3 I couldn't get it to work.

It would be great if someone could tell me what the best way to go would be and maybe how to solve it.

Comment: I've actually done this a couple of times myself as well, the only major issue when you get past any minor technical hurdles is dealing with the appropriate type conversion.  A dude I work with actually wrote a robust XML reader/writer for AS3 objects but since it was done on work time I don't think we're allowed to give out that source (would definitely at least have to check with him.  I've personally done both methods you're talking about though, that is loading XML then replacing parts, or just generating all the XML.  I think the latter is a better option.

Comment: I'm going to see if I can give this (at least the AS3 to XML, the other way around may take some more time) a shot from scratch as it'll be useful for a project I'm working on right now as well and this way I can release the source.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be better to simply work with XML literals?

```
package
{
  import flash.display.Sprite;

  public class ZutAlors extends Sprite
  {
    public function ZutAlors()
    {
      trace(messagesToXMLString('hello world'.split(' ')));
    }

    private function messageToXML(m:String, d:Date = null):XMLList
    {
      return <ret>
        <message>{m}</message>
        <date>{(d || new Date()).toString()}</date>
      </ret>.children();
    }

    private function messagesToXMLString(array:Array):XML
    {
      const ret:XML = <root />
      for each(var s:String in array)
      {
        ret.appendChild(messageToXML(s));
      }
      return ret;
    }
  }
}
```

You get a compile error if the XML was not wellformed ...

Answer (score 0):

Alright just figured I'd post an update on where I'm at so far...

This should be able to output XML for most objects, I just threw a few test cases at it so far if you'd like to start trying to debug with this and let me know if you have any parts missing or bad XML output let me know... I'm going to continue and try and work on a parser to reverse the process the XML generated by this version may change when I do that.

```
package
{
    import flash.utils.describeType;

    import mx.collections.IList;

    public class AS3ToXMLMapper
    {

        public function AS3ToXMLMapper()
        {
        }

        public static function generateXML(objectToMap:Object, basePropertyName:String="root"):String
        {
            var describeXML:XML = describeType(objectToMap);

            var xmlOutput:String = "<"+basePropertyName+" name=\""+describeXML.@name+"\" base=\""+describeXML.@base+"\">\n";

            if(describeXML.@isDynamic=="true")
            {
                for(var property:String in objectToMap)
                {
                    xmlOutput += "<"+property+">";
                    xmlOutput += objectToMap[property];
                    xmlOutput += "</"+property+">";
                }
            }
            else if(objectToMap is XML)
            {
                xmlOutput+=(objectToMap as XML).toString();
            }
            else if(objectToMap is XMLList)
            {
                xmlOutput+=(objectToMap as XMLList).toString();
            }
            else
            {
                for each(var accessor:XML in describeXML..accessor)
                {
                    xmlOutput+="\t"+exportProperty(objectToMap, accessor,true);
                }
                for each(var variable:XML in describeXML..variable)
                {
                    xmlOutput+="\t"+exportProperty(objectToMap, variable, false);
                }
            }

            xmlOutput += "</"+basePropertyName+">\n";
            trace(xmlOutput);
            return xmlOutput;
        }

        private static function exportProperty(objectToMap:Object, xmlObj:XML, isAccessor:Boolean):String
        {
            var xmlOutput:String="";
            var propName:String = xmlObj.@name.toString();
            var objectValue:Object = objectToMap[propName];
            if(!objectValue)
            {
                xmlOutput += "<"+propName+">";
                xmlOutput += "</"+propName+">";
                return xmlOutput;
            }

            if(isAccessor && xmlObj.@access != "readwrite")
            {
                return "";
            }
            if(objectValue is Array)
            {
                return exportArray(objectValue as Array, xmlObj.@name);
            }
            else if(objectValue is IList)
            {
                return exportArray((objectValue as IList).toArray(), propName);
            }
            else if(objectValue is int || objectValue is Number || objectValue is String || objectValue is uint || objectValue is Boolean)
            {
                xmlOutput += "<"+propName+" type=\""+xmlObj.@type+"\">";

                xmlOutput += objectValue;
                xmlOutput += "</"+propName+">"; 
            }
            else
            {
                return generateXML(objectValue, propName);
            }
            return xmlOutput;
        }

        private static function exportArray(array:Array, arrayName:String):String
        {
            var xmlOutput:String = "<"+arrayName+">\n";

            for each(var element:Object in array)
            {
                xmlOutput+="\t"+generateXML(element,"arrayElement");
            }

            xmlOutput += "</"+arrayName+">\n";
            return xmlOutput;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage would be like:

```
            var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
            fs.open(new File("C:\\test.xml"),FileMode.WRITE);
            var thingToExport:Object = {aProperty:"someValue"};
            var as3XMLMapper:String = AS3ToXMLMapper.generateXML(thingToExport);
            fs.writeUTFBytes(as3XMLMapper);
            fs.close();
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for this thorough answer. As I said, I am new to as3, so I am still trying to figure out how to use your code. I guess it is the best way to overwrite the whole xml. However, when I do overwrite the old text, how can I first read it and combine it with the new text? Is there a way to load the old text and maybe remove the old root tag? I tried doing that with the filestream.position element, but it would not work.

Comment: @MADMAX no problem.  Basically to use this you should be able to just copy paste the first snippet as it's own class then the second snippet is usage from within an AIR desktop app (only reason this is important is it gives you access to the FileStream class used for writing without prompting the user.  You could use this in any other  Flex context by just using the AS3ToXMLMapper.generateXML(thingToExport) which returns a string, to test you can just trace the string.

Comment: With filestream.position you're moving the "byte cursor" forward or backward in the byte stream "array".  Anytime you use a read method on a byte array buffer type object it moves the position forward.  The best bet IMO is to use readUTFBytes which will return the data as a String then manipulate the String if you want to go that route.  Ultimately though I think it's best if the entire XML is generated.  When I've done this in the past I would create a "model" object save it when appropriate and load it at start up, this way values are retained without the need to piece wise parse.

Comment: Yes, what I wanted to do is read the XML, go to the position before </root> and then continue writing from there. Sounded to me like the quickest solution, however, I could not get it to work. I will try to implement your approach now.