# how can I save data across frame in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have 6 editable text fields on stage where users have to write something and I'm currently trying get my app to save data when I switch frames. And I also want to the data could display when the app running again.
thanks

Comment: Use XML to Write and Read Data.
have a look  at this : 
[write-update-and-save-a-well-formed-xml][1]
   


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058721/write-update-and-save-a-well-formed-xml-file-in-as3

Comment: You should use shared objects to store data persistent between launches, and properties of persistent objects to store data cross-frames. I'd say drop frames altogether, but it requires major overhaul of code structure and might be too hard to execute properly.

Comment: @RaJeNdRa Not exactly, you don't need XML as data storage, and Flash (this is not AIR apparently) has shared object ready to store any kind of data, onbe just needs to learn to use them.